# Physical interpretation of Dirichlet energy for a membrane.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics, applications

In the following model of a membrane with a mass particle in it, why does the integral represents the elastic energy of the system?

Let $\Omega$ be an open connected region (the membrane) in $\Re^2$, $x\in \Omega$ and $u(x)$ be the profile of the membrane with $u=0$ at $\partial\Omega$. If $P$ is a unit mass particle we put in the membrane in position $q$, then $$\Delta u=\delta_{q} $$ is satisfied, where $\delta_{q}$ is the Dirac measure. The problem of finding the equilibrium position of the particle $P$ can be reduced to find the function u that minimizes the energy functional:
$$ E(u,q)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u(x)|^2dx +u(q)$$
which is the sum of the elastic energy and the gravitational energy (considering all physical constants equal to $1$).

Comment: It is probably a small $u$ approximation to the area functional.
$$\verb/Area/(u) - \verb/Area/(u \equiv 0) = \int_\Omega \left( \sqrt{1 + |\nabla u|^2} - 1\right) dx \approx \frac12 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 dx$$

Comment: Perhaps you can try the [physics site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions). For what it's worth, [this post there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67181/where-can-i-find-the-full-derivation-of-helfrichs-shape-equation-for-closed-mem?rq=1) is probably an overkill for your inquiry. Might or might not be helpful to you.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476334/2451